# Does family of sufficient $\sigma$-subalgebras depend on the reference measure?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, sufficient-statistics, measure-theory

Let $\{ P_{\gamma} \}$ be a parametric family of probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, such that $P_{\gamma} \ll \mu$ for all $\gamma$, for some $\sigma$-finite $\mu$. Consider the Radon-Nikodym densities $\{ \frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu} \}$.
By the Halmos-Savage factorization criterion, a $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathcal G$ is sufficient for $\{ \frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu} \}$if and only if there exists a measurable $h$, and a $\mathcal G$-measurable family $\{ g_{\gamma} \}$ such that
$$
\frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu} = g_{\gamma} \cdot h
$$
for each $\gamma$.

**Question**
Given $\{ P_{\gamma} \}$, does the family of sufficient $\sigma$-subalgebras depend on the reference measure $\mu$? In other words, suppose $\mu \ll \mu'$ and $\mu' \ll \mu$, is it true that $\mathcal G$ is sufficient for $\{ \frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu} \}$ if and only if it is sufficient for 
$\{ \frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu'} \}$?

Informally, at first glance, the answer must be yes. Sufficiency should be invariant with respect to the measure used to compute the density. Since
$$
\frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu'} 
= \frac{d P_{\gamma}}{d \mu} \frac{d \mu }{d \mu'}
= g_{\gamma} \cdot h \frac{d \mu }{d \mu'}
= g_{\gamma} \cdot h'
$$
where $h' = h \frac{d \mu }{d \mu'}$, the factorization criterion indeed says answer is yes.

On the other hand, there is an example below that, apparently, says otherwise.
Why the apparent inconsistency here?

**Example**
Consider the model is given by
$$
y_t = \rho y_{t-1}, \, t = 1, \cdots, T, \; \epsilon_i 
\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2),
$$
parametrized by $\gamma = \rho$. Take $\sigma^2$ and $y_0$ as fixed.
Let $y = (y_1, \cdots, y_T)'$.

Take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue on $\mathbb{R}^T$. Then
the RN density is (see
[this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416665/sufficient-statistic-for-gaussian-ar1))
\begin{align*}
\frac{d P_{\rho}}{d \mu}(y) &= \frac{1}{ ( \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} )^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ( \sum_{t = 1}^T (y_t - \rho y_{t-1})^2)} \\\\
&= \frac{1}{ ( \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} )^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ((1 + \rho^2) \sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1}^2 + y_T^2 - 2 \rho \sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1} y_t)^2)},
\end{align*}
which implies 
$$
\Phi(y) = (\sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1}^2,\, y_T^2,\,  \sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1} y_t)
$$
is a minimal sufficient statistic.

Now take $\mu'$ to be $P_1$, where

\begin{align*}
\frac{d P_{1}}{d \mu}(y) &= \frac{1}{ ( \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} )^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ( \sum_{t = 1}^T (y_t - y_{t-1})^2)}.
\end{align*}

So
\begin{align*}
\frac{d P_{\rho}}{d \mu'}(y) &= \frac{d P_{\rho}}{d P_1}(y) \\\\
                             &= \frac{ \frac{d P_{\rho}}{d \mu} (y)}{ \frac{d P_{1}}{d \mu} (y)} \\\\
&= e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ( \sum_{t = 1}^T (y_t - \rho y_{t-1})^2) - \sum_{t = 1}^T (y_t - y_{t-1})^2)} \\\\
&= e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ( -2 (\rho -1) \sum_{t = 1}^T y_t y_{t-1} + 
(\rho^2 - 1) \sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1})^2}.
\end{align*}

This suggests 
$$
\Phi'(y) = ( \sum_{t = 1}^T y_t y_{t-1}, \sum_{t = 1}^T y_{t-1}^2 )
$$
is minimal sufficient, apparently contradicting the minimality of $\Phi$.