# Prove the joint distribution of an AR(1) process is Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process, autoregressive, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

### I'm struggling a bit with the proof of this if anyone can help!

### I keep ending up going in circles with the conditional probabilities and I don't know what are the right steps to take.

For an $AR(1)$ model, we can write down the joint density of $(Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n)$ as

> $$p(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{(1 − φ^2)^{1/2}}{(σ^n(2π)^{n/2}} \exp\left(\frac{−(1 − φ^2)}{2σ^2y_1^2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \exp\left(\frac{−(y_{k+1} − φy_k)^2}{2σ^2}\right)$$
>
> Here we denote y as the column vector $(y_1, y_2, \cdots , y_n)^T$.
>
> Prove that the above equation can be written in the form
>
> $$p(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{(2π)^{n/2}}|\mathbf{Q}|^{1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{y}\right)$$
>
> assuming that $Y_1 = ε_1 ∼ N\left(0, \frac{σ^2}{(1 − φ^2)}\right)$, where $\mathbf{Q}$ is an $n × n$ positive definite, hence
> invertible, matrix.
>
> If you determine a form for $\mathbf{Q}$, you may assume without proof that its
> determinant satisfies $|\mathbf{Q}| = σ^{−2n}(1 − φ^2).$

**Comment**

So far, it's been easy to prove the constant part of the density, because that's a bit more obvious and just by filling in what's given. Similarly enough with $y_1$ I can draw out the $Q_{11}$ entry of the matrix and get the result, but for the product exponents, I'm stuck.

I've tried expanding out the square and I am thinking it might be somehow factor with $Q$, but because the probabilities are conditional, I'm unsure how to draw out the joint probability instead.

I've also been trying to draw out a solution using the fact that $p(y_1,...,y_n) = p(y_1)\prod_{t=1}^{n-2} p(y_t|y_{t-1})$, but nothing of use so far!

**Further**

I should also say, I think it has something to do with the innovations being Normally Distributed

Comment: Please read the wiki for the [tag:self-study] and show us what you have done so far. The someone can help you.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/416665/119261

Comment: @mdewey Apologies, have added in a comment now with what I've been trying so far!

Comment: The question is misleading, because there's actually almost nothing you need to show.  It comes down to the fact that (a) the sum of quadratic functions is quadratic and (b) the -1/2 power of the determinant yields the correct normalizing constant.  Proving (b) is a matter of computing the Jacobian of the transformation.